# Mark a location on an svg map in d3.js

Tags: svg, maps, d3.js, geojson

I am using this example from the d3.js wiki.

http://bl.ocks.org/2206590

From that, I have a map, and I want to know how to mark a single location on it.

How do I plot a small circle on this map at the location with co-ordinates  `[40.717079,-74.009628]`.

Here is the source code from the example:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("click", click);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
  .append("g")
    .attr("id", "states");

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(width)
    .translate([0, 0]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

d3.json("readme.json", function(json) {
  g.selectAll("path")
      .data(json.features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK this may not be the right answer, but this is what I did:

```
var width = 1060,
    height = 600,
    centered;


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("click", click);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
  .append("g")
    .attr("id", "states");

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(width)
    .translate([0, 100]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

    setInterval(function(){
        draw();
    },1000);

function draw(){

  d3.json("readme.json", function(json) {
    g.selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .on("click", click);

    var latitude = 35 + Math.floor(Math.random()*8);
    var longitude =  -1 * (83 + Math.floor(Math.random()*35));
    var coordinates = projection([longitude, latitude]);
    g.append('svg:circle')
    .attr('cx', coordinates[0])
    .attr('cy', coordinates[1])
    .attr('r', 2)
    .attr('stroke','red')
    .attr('fill','red');      
  });
}
```

The code works, but I suspect I am doing the wrong thing by redrawing the whole map every time I render a new co-ordinate.